# Force android studio compiler to use try-catch when using @Throws - Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, try-catch, throws

In `Java`, Android Studio has a feature to avoid calls to methods that `throws` exception without `try/catch` blocks and its auto-complete suggests to: `Add exception to method signature` or `Surround with try/catch`.

But in `Kotlin` we don't have `throws` keyword and should use `@Throws()` instead.
The problem is that `Android Studio` is no longer forcing us to surround with `try/catch`. On the other hand it does not force us to use `try/catch` for `java methods` that `throws Exception`  like `IO` progresses.

Test.java

```
public class Test {

    public void doSomeWork1(int a) throws Exception {
        if (a == -1) {
            throw new Exception("some error");
        }
    }

    public void main() {
        doSomeWork1(-1);
    }
}
```

Test.kt

```
class Test {

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun doSomeWork1(a: Int) {
        if (a == -1) {
            throw Exception("some error")
        }
    }

    fun main() {
        doSomeWork1(-1)
    }
}
```

[image: Test.java]

`Test.java` class that android studio not allowing us to compile my code without using `try catch`.

[image: Test.kt]

`Test.kt` class that is compiling without an error.

[image: android studio auto-complete suggestions]

`Test.java` android studio auto-complete suggestions

Is there any way to force `android studio` for `kotlin` language to use `try/catch` for these `functions/methods` or at least gives us a `warning`?

Comment: Here's a plugin that maybe would show warnings, at least for the Java checked exceptions. Not sure how the `@Throws` annotation would be treated. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12673-csense--kotlin-checked-exceptions You might also want to read up some more on the debate about the existence of checked exceptions. There are reasons almost all languages that are younger than Java don't support them.

Comment: Kotlin does not handle checked exceptions [by design](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exceptions.html#checked-exceptions), `@Throws` is just for JVM/C interoperability.